# Calling commands from ruby not working in docker image

Tags: ruby, docker, tesseract

I have created a docker image and installed tesseract on this image using [this](https://github.com/tesseract-shadow/tesseract-ocr-compilation/blob/master/Dockerfile) docker file with the scripts provided in the same repo. I have then added my own little ruby app so that i can send an image and get the results returned:

```
require_relative 'bundle/bundler/setup'
require 'sinatra'
require "json"
require 'sinatra/base'
require "sinatra/activerecord"
require 'sinatra'
require 'fileutils'
require "carrierwave"
require 'carrierwave/datamapper'
require "carrierwave/orm/activerecord"
require_relative 'models/image'
require_relative 'data_mapper_setup'

set :protection, except: [ :json_csrf ]

port = ENV['PORT'] || 8080
puts "STARTING SINATRA on port #{port}"
set :port, port
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.root = File.dirname(__FILE__)
end

get '/' do
  ({"Hello" => "World!"}).to_json
end

post '/extractText' do
  begin
    path = File.dirname(__FILE__)
    billID = params[:billID]
    image = Image.new(file: params[:file])
    file = File.new("#{path}#{image.file.url}")
    system("tesseract #{file} --psm 6 resultsFile.txt")
    results = File.read("resultsFile.txt")
  rescue
    status 402
    return "Error reading image"
  end
  status 200
  return resultsFile.to_json
end
```

My dockerfile has been adapted slightly to look like this:

```
    FROM ubuntu:16.04

    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        autoconf \
        autoconf-archive \
        automake \
        build-essential \
        checkinstall \
        cmake \
        g++ \
        git \
        libcairo2-dev \
        libcairo2-dev \
        libicu-dev \
        libicu-dev \
        libjpeg8-dev \
        libjpeg8-dev \
        libpango1.0-dev \
        libpango1.0-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libtiff5-dev \
        libtiff5-dev \
        libtool \
        pkg-config \
        wget \
        xzgv \
        zlib1g-dev


    # SSH for diagnostic
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --allow-downgrades --allow-remove-essential --allow-change-held-packages openssh-server
    RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
    RUN echo 'root:root' | chpasswd
    RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    # SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
    RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd
    ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
    RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

    EXPOSE 22
    CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]

    # Directories
    ENV SCRIPTS_DIR /home/scripts
    ENV PKG_DIR /home/pkg
    ENV BASE_DIR /home/workspace
    ENV LEP_REPO_URL https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica.git
    ENV LEP_SRC_DIR ${BASE_DIR}/leptonica
    ENV TES_REPO_URL https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract.git
    ENV TES_SRC_DIR ${BASE_DIR}/tesseract
    ENV TESSDATA_PREFIX /usr/local/share/tessdata

    RUN mkdir ${SCRIPTS_DIR}
    RUN mkdir ${PKG_DIR}
    RUN mkdir ${BASE_DIR}
    RUN mkdir ${TESSDATA_PREFIX}

    COPY ./container-scripts/* ${SCRIPTS_DIR}/
    RUN chmod +x ${SCRIPTS_DIR}/*
    RUN ${SCRIPTS_DIR}/repos_clone.sh
    RUN ${SCRIPTS_DIR}/tessdata_download.sh

    RUN groupadd -r tesseract && useradd -r -g tesseract tesseract
    USER tesseract

    FROM iron/ruby

    WORKDIR /app

    ADD . /app
    ADD ./bin/textcleaner /usr/local/bin

    ENTRYPOINT ["ruby", "app.rb"]
```

Using the following to setup:
        docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/app -w /app iron/ruby:dev bundle update
        docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/app -w /app iron/ruby:dev bundle install --standalone --clean
        sudo chmod -R a+rw .bundle
        sudo chmod -R a+rw bundle

and this to run:

```
docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/app -w /app -p 8080:8080 iron/ruby ruby app.rb
```

It all runs fine but when it gets to `system("tesseract #{file} --psm 6 resultsFile.txt")` i get an output in terminal saying `sh: tesseract: not found` and i dont know why. tesseract should be installed fine.

Also if i add a similar command like `system("docker run tesseract #{file} --psm 6 resultsFile.txt")`

I get the error: `sh: docker: not found`

Im sure im missing something simple that is me misunderstanding docker somehow but i dont know what and why i cant call these commands from a ruby file.

Another thing that i though would work is i have added a script file(`ADD ./bin/textcleaner /usr/local/bin'`) that helps to pre-process the image passed but my ruby app cant find it either when i call `system("bin/textcleaner #{file} #{file})`

Any help would be great

Update for more info:

O also used the following github link to help me create the Dockerfile i have come up with, which i have tested and works. https://github.com/dphiggs01/docker-tesseract/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: Why would you assume that /usr/local/bin is in your application's PATH inside the container?

Comment: I was following a similar repo https://github.com/dphiggs01/docker-tesseract/blob/master/Dockerfile, it also doent give an error when being called about the directory/file existing